# Is there a viable way to cluster geo-spatial data while considering boundary line segments?

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to cluster lat/long coordinates into a specified number of densely created clusters but need to consider line segment boundaries - if the line segment between any two data points intersects a list of specified line segments (say 4 line segments --> Identified by start/end lat/long) then the points should not be clustered together. Because this is geo-spatial data I am looking to cluster around specific "geographies" that can not easily be interpreted from the clustering algorithms I am currently using. An initial thought was to modify the upper triangle of a distance matrix that is inputted into the clustering algorithm, looping through each entry of the triangle, checking the line segment against the "boundaries" and replacing the distance with a large value if intersection is found. This however is incredibly computationally hard (or at least the configuration I have set-up), and I am unable to manipulate the data in a reasonable amount of time.

To give a representation of the scale, these data sets may consist of anywhere form 1,000-50,000 Lat/Long pairs.

I have attempted to "structure" the data by utilizing the "kneighbors_graph" in Python to develop a connectivity matrix based on the KNN algorithm but it does not solve the issue (with varying values of k).Example followed: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_ward_structured_vs_unstructured.html
This ended up utilizing an Agglomerative Clustering approach which did not yield the results I was hoping (clusters still spanning across different geographies, and uneven cluster sizes - one as majority of the dataset).

In R I have attempted the aforementioned line segment method to adjust the distance matrix being fed into the k-means algorithm, but stopped the code execution after about an hour of computation (and the upper triangle was barely processed!), which makes me think it has to do with my implementation. I will paste my method below (the line segments are read in from a csv file as a dataframe with start_lat,start_long,end_lat,end_long -hence the "barrier[k,...]" calls)

Any and all help is appreciated in terms of general ideology on how to approach the problem or even specific code implementations that could speed up the processing idea I've mentioned. I also looked into the sweeping line algorithm but have not been able to wrap my head around an efficient way to implement that into the overall script.

```
#Load CSV of barrier line segments
barrier <- read.csv("LineSegments.csv")

#Create distance matrix from Lat/Long Dataframe
distMatrix <- as.matrix(dist(LatLongDf))
q <- nrow(distMatrix)

#Loop through upper triangle of matrix without diagonal
for (i in 1:(q-1)){
    for (j in (i+1):q) {

        #Grab row/column index of matrix (point IDs) and remap to original DF for point lat/longs
        c1 <- c(LatLongDf[rownames(distMatrix)[i][1],LatLongDf[rownames(distMatrix)[i][2])
        c2 <- c(LatLongDf[rownames(distMatrix)[j][1],LatLongDf[rownames(distMatrix)[j][2])

        #Loop through inputted line segments
        for (k in 1:nrow(barrier)) {
             #Get point of intersection between two segments
             dp <- line.line.intersection(c1,c2,c(barrier[k,2],barrier[k,3]),c(barrier[k,4],barrier[k,5]),interior.only = TRUE)
             #If the lines do not intersect then set distance to max
             if (is.na(dp[1])) {
                  distMatrix[i,j] <- max(distMatrix)
                  break
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Consider migrating it to gis.stackexchange.com for advice on general approaches

Comment: K-means does *not* use a distance matrix as input! It needs Euclidean vectors to compute means!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the lines to *first* split your data, then cluster only the parts? That will certainly be the easiest solution.

K-means does not use a distance matrix, so your approach will not work. It needs to compute the means of vectors, only minimizes squared Euclidean distances because the arithmetic mean is a L2 best center. You cannot just use a different distance with k-means.
If you want to use k-means on geo data, you better project the data to a suitable kartesian coordinate, such as UTM zones.

The R interpreter is *slow*. Incredibly slow. If you want the code to be fast, avoid anything that is not "vectorised" or even better a call to some fast Fortran or C library.